# jQuery show & hide if not containing text in div above

Tags: jquery, hide, this, show, show-hide

I'm trying to display 'dd' content if the above 'dt' contains the following 'Candidate Name:' else hide 'dd', My snippet below is almost there but it shows all 'dd' not just the ones with the above text 'Candidate Name:' If anyone could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it.

**JS CODE:**

```
$('.order_table_item .variation dt').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Candidate Name:') {
        $('.order_table_item .variation dt').next().show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you knock up a fiddle to illustrate please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`$('.order_table_item .variation dt').next().show();` with `$(this).next().show();`

`$(this)` refers to the current element

using `$('.order_table_item .variation dt').next().show();` will show all `$('.order_table_item .variation dt').next()`

**js**

```
$('.order_table_item .variation dt').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Candidate Name:') {
        $(this).next().show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: @AdamWadsworth welome Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.order_table_item .variation dt').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Candidate Name:') {
        $(this).next().show();
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```